# How to run distinct on string of case class in a list?

Tags: scala

```
scala> case class Color (name: String, shade: String)
defined class Color

scala> val colors = List[Color](Color("red", "light"), Color("green", "dark"), Color("red", "dark"))
colors: List[Color] = List(Color(red,light), Color(green,dark), Color(red,dark))
```

I need to find out if there are any duplicate shades (i.e. `"dark"` is a duplicate in the list above)

How can I do this? I can't just run `colors.distinct` because that will check for distinct on all properties (`name and shade`) but I'm only interested in finding duplicates of `shade`

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: You wouldn't *find* duplicates with `distinct` anyway, so your question is not 100% clear.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to know if there is any duplicates, I think this could be a solution:

```
colors.map(_.shade).distinct
```

If the length of that is less than the length of `colors`, you have duplicates in the list. That is, if:

```
colors.map(_.shade).distinct.size == colors.size
```

Then there aren't duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution would be to `groupBy` and then take `head`:

```
  case class Color (name: String, shade: String)
  val colors = List[Color](Color("red", "light"), Color("green", "dark"), Color("red", "dark"))
  println(colors.groupBy(_.shade).map(x => x._2.head).toList)
```

Another way is by using `Scala reflect`:

```
  import scala.reflect.internal.util.Collections
  println(Collections.distinctBy(colors)(_.shade))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's introduce new function

```
def distinctBy[A, B](xs: List[A])(key: A => B): List[A] = {
  val seen = mutable.HashSet[B]()
  xs.filter { x =>
    val k = key(x)
    if (!seen(k)) {
      seen += k
      true
    } else false
  }
}
```

and

```
distinctBy(colors)(_.shade)
```

results in

```
res0: List[Color] = List(Color(red,light), Color(green,dark))
```